# iOS 7 - Hide status bar on a child view controller

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, xamarin.ios, ios7, statusbar

`UIApplication.SharedApplication.SetStatusBarHidden`(MonoTouch code, but also applies to Obj-C) does the job for iOS 6, but for iOS 7 we must:

1. Invoke `SetNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate ()` on the view controller (e.g.: a view controller that is showing a fullscreen image)
2. Override `PrefersStatusBarHidden ()` on the same view controller.

However the view controller mentioned above is embedded in a navigation controller, which is also embedded in a slideout menu. Even though all embedded view controllers are added to the hierarchy using `AddChildViewController()`, attempting to update the status bar in a child view controller has no effect.

Any ideas?

---

**EDIT**

```
Window.RootViewController (Menu)
|___ ViewControllerA (Navigation Bar)
     |___ ViewControllerB (Actual View controller)
```

Where `ViewControllerB` wants to hide/show the status bar

Comment: Looks like the `ChildViewControllerForStatusBarHidden ()` override is the way to go.

Answer (score 7):

ViewControllerA should override childViewControllerForStatusBarHidden and return ViewControllerB.

```
- (UIViewController *)childViewControllerForStatusBarHidden {
    return _viewControllerB;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It does not appear entirely what you attempt to do. If you simple want to hide the statusbar in all child viewcontrollers, you could set the new plist property`UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance`.

> ... If you prefer to opt out of this behavior and set the status bar
>   style by using the UIApplication statusBarStyle method, add the
>   UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance key to an app’s Info.plist
>   file and give it the value NO.

source:https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TransitionGuide/Bars.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013174-CH8-SW1

The source is BTW a really good reference to all kinds of information related to the handling of `UINavigationBar` and `UIStatusBar` in iOS7.

Comment: Link is broken!