# Transparent status bar for OS-supplied view controllers

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uiimagepickercontroller, statusbar

My app allows users to import video and perform a few other actions like send an email. When I call the standard code to present these view controllers (example below), the result is that scrollable elements appear underneath the status bar, which is hideous. My own View Controllers do not suffer from this glitch. The problem seems to occur in iOS 7 and 8.

I see many related questions, but most of them address dealing with the status bar in your own view controllers, and I've already done that. My question is about dealing with view controllers I get from the OS.

Any idea what we might be doing (e.g. in storyboard) to cause this? Did I forget or miss an obvious step? It's very ugly and distracting and a fix would be fantastic. I don't see this in any other app.

```
UIImagePickerController *mediaUI = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
mediaUI.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

// Displays saved movies from the Camera Roll album.
mediaUI.mediaTypes = @[(__bridge NSString *)kUTTypeMovie];

mediaUI.allowsEditing = YES;

mediaUI.delegate = self; //with or without this, the glitch appears

[self presentViewController:mediaUI animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Here's what it looks like:

[image]

Comment: This may help; https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1797/_index.html

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I could find was to remove the status bar. This might be possible via davidisdk's answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18934565/ios-7-hide-status-bar-on-a-child-view-controller?rq=1), but I did it by subclassing UIImagePicker (and a few other classes) like this:

```
@interface NoStatusBarImagePickerController : UIImagePickerController
@end

@implementation NoStatusBarImagePickerController
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {
    return YES;
}
- (UIViewController *)childViewControllerForStatusBarHidden {
    return nil;
}
@end
```